# Random Kernel Panic on Ubuntu 22.04.3, Raspberry Pi 2b

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi, arm

I have an old Raspberry Pi 2B v1.1 (BCM2836). Wanna use it for multipurpose home mini server.

Flashed and running Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 armhf just fine. After few hours, kernel panic happened, had to restart the RPi to resume its operation.

Currently running kernel 5.15.0-1041-raspi.

As kernel panic logs can't be traced, I attached the HDMI port to external monitor to further investigate the issue.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt.
...
...
bcm2836_arm_irqchip_handle_irq ...
...
```

Capure of kernel panic attached, any ideas to resolve the issue ?

[kernel panic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3fSO.jpg)

dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] kernel: Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-1041-raspi (buildd@bos01-arm64-017) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #44-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Oct 10 13:07:27 UTC 2023 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-1041.44-raspi 5.15.122)
[    0.000000] kernel: CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=30c5387d
[    0.000000] kernel: CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] kernel: CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] kernel: OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1
[    0.000000] kernel: random: crng init done
[    0.000000] kernel: Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] kernel: efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] kernel: Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x0000000037400000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] kernel: OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] kernel: Zone ranges:
[    0.000000] kernel:   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000002fffffff]
[    0.000000] kernel:   Normal   empty
[    0.000000] kernel:   HighMem  [mem 0x0000000030000000-0x000000003b3fffff]
[    0.000000] kernel: Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] kernel: Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000] kernel:   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003b3fffff]
[    0.000000] kernel: Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003b3fffff]
[    0.000000] kernel: percpu: Embedded 17 pages/cpu s40012 r8192 d21428 u69632
[    0.000000] kernel: pcpu-alloc: s40012 r8192 d21428 u69632 alloc=17*4096
[    0.000000] kernel: pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] kernel: Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 240960
[    0.000000] kernel: Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1920 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1080 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash
[    0.000000] kernel: Unknown kernel command line parameters "fixrtc splash", will be passed to user space.
[    0.000000] kernel: Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] kernel: Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] kernel: allocated 970752 bytes of page_ext
[    0.000000] kernel: mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] kernel: Memory: 836336K/970752K available (12288K kernel code, 1284K rwdata, 4156K rodata, 2048K init, 515K bss, 68880K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved, 118784K highmem)
[    0.000000] kernel: SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] kernel: ftrace: allocating 41809 entries in 123 pages
[    0.000000] kernel: ftrace: allocated 123 pages with 6 groups
[    0.000000] kernel: trace event string verifier disabled
[    0.000000] kernel: rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] kernel:         Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] kernel:         Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] kernel:         Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] kernel: rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] kernel: NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] kernel: arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] kernel: clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000002] kernel: sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000027] kernel: Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000571] kernel: Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000682] kernel: printk: console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000777] kernel: Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=76800)
[    0.000819] kernel: CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.000924] kernel: pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001272] kernel: LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.001384] kernel: Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.001589] kernel: AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.001944] kernel: Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.001987] kernel: Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.004991] kernel: CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.005031] kernel: CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 15, mpidr 80000f00
[    0.007687] kernel: Setting up static identity map for 0x200000 - 0x20003c
[    0.008126] kernel: rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.010190] kernel: EFI services will not be available.
[    0.011571] kernel: smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.013828] kernel: CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.013851] kernel: CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 15, mpidr 80000f01
[    0.016196] kernel: CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.016217] kernel: CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 15, mpidr 80000f02
[    0.018420] kernel: CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.018438] kernel: CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 15, mpidr 80000f03
[    0.018715] kernel: smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.018756] kernel: SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.018779] kernel: CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.018794] kernel: CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.020539] kernel: devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.043333] kernel: VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.043745] kernel: clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.043799] kernel: futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.049113] kernel: pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.050539] kernel: DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.051724] kernel: NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.058354] kernel: DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.065469] kernel: audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.066009] kernel: audit: type=2000 audit(0.064:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.067248] kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.067272] kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
[    0.067290] kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.067307] kernel: thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
[    0.067711] kernel: cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.067803] kernel: cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.069008] kernel: hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.069039] kernel: hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.069672] kernel: Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.079420] kernel: bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.100849] kernel: raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2022-10-26T11:10:35, variant start
[    0.104876] kernel: raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is c72ad6b26ff40c91ef776b847436094ee63fabee
[    0.164978] kernel: kprobes: kprobe jump-optimization is enabled. All kprobes are optimized if possible.
[    0.166659] kernel: HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.187793] kernel: bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.193910] kernel: iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
[    0.193942] kernel: iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: strict mode 
[    0.196659] kernel: SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.197084] kernel: libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.197563] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.197663] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.197783] kernel: usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.198328] kernel: pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.198350] kernel: pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.198399] kernel: PTP clock support registered
[    0.198864] kernel: EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.201656] kernel: NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.201681] kernel: NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.201699] kernel: NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.201893] kernel: NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.203915] kernel: clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.368788] kernel: VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.368964] kernel: VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.370527] kernel: AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.390268] kernel: NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    0.390631] kernel: IP idents hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.393374] kernel: tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
[    0.393449] kernel: Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.393487] kernel: TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.393618] kernel: TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.393821] kernel: TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.394297] kernel: MPTCP token hash table entries: 1024 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.394442] kernel: UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.394525] kernel: UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.395001] kernel: NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
[    0.395078] kernel: NET: Registered PF_XDP protocol family
[    0.395113] kernel: PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.395747] kernel: Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    0.397212] kernel: hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    0.432537] kernel: Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.432699] kernel: Key type blacklist registered
[    0.433265] kernel: workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=18 bucket_order=4
[    0.447263] kernel: zbud: loaded
[    0.450821] kernel: squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    0.453216] kernel: fuse: init (API version 7.34)
[    0.619768] kernel: Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.619849] kernel: Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.620357] kernel: bounce: pool size: 64 pages
[    0.620557] kernel: Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 242)
[    0.621078] kernel: io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.631310] kernel: bcm2708_fb soc:fb: FB found 1 display(s)
[    0.687606] kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    0.728358] kernel: bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Registered framebuffer for display 0, size 1920x1080
[    0.881865] kernel: bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.882897] kernel: vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    0.907524] kernel: loop: module loaded
[    0.909393] kernel: bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    0.919721] kernel: tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.920970] kernel: PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.921607] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    0.921722] kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.921812] kernel: ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.921889] kernel: ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.922001] kernel: ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.922219] kernel: ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.922306] kernel: uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.922531] kernel: dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    0.922875] kernel: dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    0.922895] kernel: dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    0.922912] kernel: dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    0.922938] kernel: Module dwc_common_port init
[    0.924225] kernel: mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.925464] kernel: i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.931367] kernel: bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    0.931579] kernel: device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[    0.931977] kernel: device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.932684] kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: 4.45.0-ioctl (2021-03-22) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.937174] kernel: sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.937215] kernel: sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.938981] kernel: sdhost: log_buf @ 73355e22 (f7510000)
[    1.008636] kernel: mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    1.009102] kernel: sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.011292] kernel: ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.012155] kernel: hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.022276] kernel: drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    1.023625] kernel: NET: Registered PF_INET6 protocol family
[    1.083797] kernel: mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.088446] kernel: mmc0: new high speed SDXC card at address e624
[    1.090110] kernel: mmcblk0: mmc0:e624 SB64G 59.5 GiB 
[    1.096030] kernel:  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    1.097179] kernel: mmcblk0: mmc0:e624 SB64G 59.5 GiB (quirks 0x00004000)
[    1.612188] kernel: Freeing initrd memory: 35912K
[    1.674494] kernel: Segment Routing with IPv6
[    1.674625] kernel: In-situ OAM (IOAM) with IPv6
[    1.674784] kernel: NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    1.675202] kernel: Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.675808] kernel: ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    1.675850] kernel: Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.677150] kernel: registered taskstats version 1
[    1.677272] kernel: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.685682] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 80cb756a3b4cd508a1a1a557fde12835cb9eef2f'
[    1.694006] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Live Patch Signing: 14df34d1a87cf37625abec039ef2bf521249b969'
[    1.701586] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Kernel Module Signing: 88f752e560a1e0737e31163a466ad7b70a850c19'
[    1.701612] kernel: blacklist: Loading compiled-in revocation X.509 certificates
[    1.701761] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing: 61482aa2830d0ab2ad5af10b7250da9033ddcef0'
[    1.701896] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017): 242ade75ac4a15e50d50c84b0d45ff3eae707a03'
[    1.702033] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (ESM 2018): 365188c1d374d6b07c3c8f240f8ef722433d6a8b'
[    1.702173] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2019): c0746fd6c5da3ae827864651ad66ae47fe24b3e8'
[    1.702349] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v1): a8d54bbb3825cfb94fa13c9f8a594a195c107b8d'
[    1.702499] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v2): 4cf046892d6fd3c9a5b03f98d845f90851dc6a8c'
[    1.702674] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2021 v3): 100437bb6de6e469b581e61cd66bce3ef4ed53af'
[    1.702823] kernel: Loaded X.509 cert 'Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (Ubuntu Core 2019): c1d57b8f6b743f23ee41f4f7ee292f06eecadfb9'
[    1.704169] kernel: Key type .fscrypt registered
[    1.704193] kernel: Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    1.744683] kernel: cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    1.800015] kernel: Key type encrypted registered
[    1.800067] kernel: AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    1.800140] kernel: ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    1.800201] kernel: ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
[    1.800256] kernel: ima: No architecture policies found
[    1.800408] kernel: evm: Initialising EVM extended attributes:
[    1.800422] kernel: evm: security.selinux
[    1.800436] kernel: evm: security.SMACK64
[    1.800448] kernel: evm: security.SMACK64EXEC
[    1.800460] kernel: evm: security.SMACK64TRANSMUTE
[    1.800472] kernel: evm: security.SMACK64MMAP
[    1.800484] kernel: evm: security.apparmor
[    1.800496] kernel: evm: security.ima
[    1.800508] kernel: evm: security.capability
[    1.800519] kernel: evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    1.810792] kernel: uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    1.811007] kernel: 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 114, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.811375] kernel: printk: console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    1.817943] kernel: of_cfs_init
[    1.818171] kernel: of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.832005] kernel: Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2048K
[    1.862207] kernel: Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found
[    1.862278] kernel: Run /init as init process
[    1.862304] kernel:   with arguments:
[    1.862325] kernel:     /init
[    1.862343] kernel:     fixrtc
[    1.862360] kernel:     splash
[    1.862377] kernel:   with environment:
[    1.862394] kernel:     HOME=/
[    1.862411] kernel:     TERM=linux
[    3.000962] kernel: usb_phy_generic phy: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.001409] kernel: usb_phy_generic phy: dummy supplies not allowed for exclusive requests
[    3.734103] kernel: Core Release: 2.80a
[    3.734167] kernel: Setting default values for core params
[    3.734210] kernel: Finished setting default values for core params
[    3.957524] kernel: Using Buffer DMA mode
[    3.957558] kernel: Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    3.957572] kernel: Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    3.957586] kernel: OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    3.957610] kernel: Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    3.974896] kernel: 
[    3.974934] kernel: WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1072: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = f093f000 dma = 0x00000000f7514000 len=9024
[    3.975002] kernel: FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
                       Non-periodic Split Transactions
                       Periodic Split Transactions
                       High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
                       Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    3.975024] kernel: dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    3.975362] kernel: 
[    3.975377] kernel: WARN::hcd_init_fiq:457: FIQ on core 1
[    3.975397] kernel: 
[    3.975402] kernel: WARN::hcd_init_fiq:458: FIQ ASM at c0a6db1c length 36
[    3.975424] kernel: 
[    3.975428] kernel: WARN::hcd_init_fiq:496: MPHI regs_base at f0810000
[    3.975515] kernel: dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    3.977842] kernel: dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    3.977945] kernel: dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 89, io mem 0x00000000
[    3.978014] kernel: Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    3.978027] kernel: Init: Power Port (0)
[    3.978655] kernel: usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    3.978685] kernel: usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    3.978702] kernel: usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    3.978718] kernel: usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.0-1041-raspi dwc_otg_hcd
[    3.978733] kernel: usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    3.980267] kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    3.980434] kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    4.188261] kernel: Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    4.375965] kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    4.376192] kernel: Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    4.584431] kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    4.584484] kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    4.586072] kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    4.586292] kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    4.875975] kernel: usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    4.976453] kernel: usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    4.976489] kernel: usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    4.980173] kernel: smsc95xx v2.0.0
[    5.112112] kernel: SMSC LAN8700 usb-001:003:01: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=usb-001:003:01, irq=POLL)
[    5.116375] kernel: smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:d8:77:52
[    5.130356] kernel: smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 enxb827ebd87752: renamed from eth0
[    5.204034] kernel: usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    5.308958] kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8179, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    5.309010] kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.309030] kernel: usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11n NIC
[    5.309047] kernel: usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    5.309063] kernel: usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00E04C0001
[    5.391960] kernel: usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    5.492736] kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8179, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    5.492778] kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.492796] kernel: usb 1-1.4: Product: 802.11n NIC
[    5.492812] kernel: usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    5.492826] kernel: usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 00E04C0001
[    6.055983] kernel: raid6: neonx8   gen()   580 MB/s
[    6.123936] kernel: raid6: neonx8   xor()   463 MB/s
[    6.191946] kernel: raid6: neonx4   gen()   810 MB/s
[    6.259938] kernel: raid6: neonx4   xor()   616 MB/s
[    6.327928] kernel: raid6: neonx2   gen()   812 MB/s
[    6.395931] kernel: raid6: neonx2   xor()   591 MB/s
[    6.463953] kernel: raid6: neonx1   gen()   666 MB/s
[    6.531940] kernel: raid6: neonx1   xor()   485 MB/s
[    6.599943] kernel: raid6: int32x8  gen()   210 MB/s
[    6.667951] kernel: raid6: int32x8  xor()   130 MB/s
[    6.735928] kernel: raid6: int32x4  gen()   217 MB/s
[    6.803927] kernel: raid6: int32x4  xor()   141 MB/s
[    6.871980] kernel: raid6: int32x2  gen()   260 MB/s
[    6.939974] kernel: raid6: int32x2  xor()   160 MB/s
[    7.007982] kernel: raid6: int32x1  gen()   280 MB/s
[    7.075978] kernel: raid6: int32x1  xor()   154 MB/s
[    7.075995] kernel: raid6: using algorithm neonx2 gen() 812 MB/s
[    7.076008] kernel: raid6: xor() 591 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    7.076021] kernel: raid6: using neon recovery algorithm
[    7.094523] kernel: xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    7.105837] kernel:    arm4regs        :   883 MB/sec
[    7.124462] kernel:    8regs           :   723 MB/sec
[    7.136372] kernel:    32regs          :   829 MB/sec
[    7.144393] kernel:    neon            :  1232 MB/sec
[    7.144408] kernel: xor: using function: neon (1232 MB/sec)
[    7.153842] kernel: async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    7.408767] kernel: uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    8.057248] kernel: Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-generic, zoned=yes, fsverity=no
[   10.687957] kernel: EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[   12.070422] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[   12.209067] systemd[1]: systemd 249.11-0ubuntu3.10 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[   12.210386] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[   12.213293] systemd[1]: Hostname set to <pi-host>.
[   14.414536] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Graphical Interface.
[   14.451347] systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/modprobe.
[   14.456942] systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/serial-getty.
[   14.462734] systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
[   14.466270] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[   14.467153] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[   14.469456] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   14.471033] systemd[1]: Reached target Slice Units.
[   14.471324] systemd[1]: Reached target Mounting snaps.
[   14.471654] systemd[1]: Reached target Swaps.
[   14.472126] systemd[1]: Reached target Local Verity Protected Volumes.
[   14.473120] systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[   14.474490] systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[   14.475822] systemd[1]: Listening on multipathd control socket.
[   14.477263] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[   14.478362] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   14.478925] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[   14.481014] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[   14.482076] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[   14.483360] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   14.485589] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[   14.487064] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[   14.488234] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[   14.522898] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[   14.535360] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[   14.549473] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[   14.562561] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[   14.584691] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[   14.600847] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   14.616038] systemd[1]: Starting Create List of Static Device Nodes...
[   14.631719] systemd[1]: Starting Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[   14.632896] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in LXD - agent being skipped.
[   14.648101] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module configfs...
[   14.662563] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[   14.678025] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
[   14.697552] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module fuse...
[   14.698572] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
[   14.701962] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[   14.730826] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   14.746632] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[   14.765339] systemd[1]: Starting Coldplug All udev Devices...
[   14.807159] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   14.813772] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   14.817859] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[   14.821301] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[   14.838310] systemd[1]: Finished Create List of Static Device Nodes.
[   14.844953] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Deactivated successfully.
[   14.851357] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module configfs.
```